# Expectation of operator norm between the identity and Haar random unitary

Tags: integration

I want to evaluate the following expectation.
$$\mathbb{E}_{U\text{~Haar}} ||I-U||$$
where $||\cdot||$ is the operator norm (i.e., the maximum eigenvalue.). This is equivalent to the integral of

$$
\frac{1}{n!(2\pi)^n}\max_i|1-e^{i\theta_i}|\prod_{j\le k}|e^{i\theta_j}-e^{i\theta_k}|^2 
$$
over $(\theta_i,...,\theta_n)\in[0,2\pi]^{\times n}$.
How do I calculate this integral?

Comment: You can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`.